# Rollback Transaction on just one column - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm writing a trigger right now and I'm curious if it's possible to rollback a transaction on just a single column of an update that might affect multiple columns?

Comment: Do you want to undo the modification of just one column, and keep other modifications? It is possible, just it is not called a rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a transaction rolls back everything between begin trans and rollback. Plus that would require a special syntax for the rollback statement where you (supposedly) would choose which column to rollback.

Comment: Sounds good. I didn't think there was, just wanted to check with the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to undo the modification of just one column, and keep other modifications? It is possible, you can retrieve old values from deleted virtual table in your trigger. It is not called a rollback, but you can do that.

Comment: I think this might be useful. Can you elaborate a little more on this? I've tried querying the INSERTED table (view?) in the trigger but the problem is that I might not know which fields were being updated and therefore wouldn't know how to act accordingly.